# Haskell: Sort using Monoid and Foldable

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement sorting using `Monoid` and `Foldable`. This is what I have so far. It is really slow. However, when I write the same functions without `Monoid` or `Foldable`, it is reasonably fast. Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

```
newtype MergeL a = MergeL { getMergeL :: [a] } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord a => Monoid (MergeL a) where
  mempty      = MergeL []
  mappend l r = MergeL $ merge (getMergeL l) (getMergeL r)



comp :: a -> MergeL a
comp a = MergeL [a]

instance Foldable MergeL where
  foldMap f xs =
    case divide xs of
      (MergeL [], MergeL []) -> mempty
      (MergeL l , MergeL []) -> foldMap f l
      (MergeL [], MergeL r)  -> foldMap f r
      (MergeL l , MergeL r)  -> foldMap f l <> foldMap f r

divide :: MergeL a -> (MergeL a, MergeL a)
-- now uses leftHalf and rightHalf
divide xs = (MergeL $ leftHalf ls, MergeL $ rightHalf ls)
  where
    ls  = getMergeL  xs

foldSort :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> [a]
foldSort = getMergeL . foldMap comp


mon :: Integer -> IO ()
mon n = (print . last . getMergeL  . foldMap comp) $ MergeL [n,n - 1 ..0]
```

Shared helper functions:

```
leftHalf :: [a] -> [a]
leftHalf xs = take (length xs `div` 2) xs

rightHalf :: [a] -> [a]
rightHalf xs = drop (length xs `div` 2) xs

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
        | (x <= y)  = x:(merge xs (y:ys))
        | otherwise = y:(merge (x:xs) ys)
```

Here is the implementation of the the sort function without `Monoid`. It uses the same `leftHalf` and `rightHalf` for  spliting the list and the same `merge` for merging the lists:

```
mergesort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
mergesort [] = []
mergesort [x] = [x]
mergesort xs = merge (mergesort (leftHalf xs)) (mergesort (rightHalf xs))

plain :: Integer -> IO ()
plain n = (print . last . mergesort)  [n,n - 1 ..0]
```

The difference in performance is:

```
 λ> mon 4000
4000
(2.20 secs, 1,328,105,368 bytes)
 λ> plain 4000
4000
(0.03 secs, 11,130,816 bytes)
```

Comment: (1) "However, when I write the same functions without `Monoid` or `Foldable`, it is reasonably fast" -- I suggest adding this alternative implementation to your question. (2) As a preliminary guess, `divide` looks like something that could cause trouble: for one, `length` followed by `take` and `drop` likely means the lists are kept in memory for longer than you'd want, as multiple runs through them are necessary. (3) Note that the combination of `take n` and `drop n` can be replaced by `splitAt n`.

Comment: A quick note: looks like you're pulling things out of `MergeL` only to push it back in a *lot* (in every call to `divide`, for instance). This is a good sign that you want to define a `Functor` instance for `MergeL` so you can `fmap length (xs :: MergeL a)`

Comment: `divide` then becomes `fmap (flip div 2 . length &&& id >>> uncurry splitAt)`

Comment: @AdamSmith `fmap` for `MergeL` would act on the list elements, not on the list itself.

Comment: @duplode oh shoot, right, because `newtype /= data`. Whoops!

Comment: @AdamSmith It boils down to how the type is parameterised. You'd have your `fmap` if matthias' type were `newtype MergeL a = MergeL a` -- but then it wouldn't be a list in spirit any longer.

Comment: @duplode I have added the `mergesort` function above. I have also rewritten `divide` to explicitly use the same `leftHalf` and `rightHalf` functions that the non monoidal `mergesort` uses. Also note that `splitAt` is defined `splitAt n xs =  (take n xs, drop n xs)` in source. I know that I am calling `length xs` twice here, but I have left it like that just to show that that is not the main problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is quite easy to miss (in fact, I overlooked it until I threw in a [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) in `divide`). One of your `foldMap` cases is:

```
(MergeL l , MergeL r)  -> foldMap f l <> foldMap f r
```

There, `foldMap` is being called on `l` and `r`, which are plain lists, as opposed to `MergeL`-wrapped lists. That being so, `l` and `r` are not `divide`d; rather, they are merged element by element. As a consequence, the sorting becomes quadratic.

In addition to using the `MergeL` `foldMap` recursively, fixing the instance also requires adding extra cases for single element lists, as dividing them is as problematic as dividing empty lists:

```
instance Foldable MergeL where
  foldMap f xs =
    case divide xs of
      (MergeL [], MergeL []) -> mempty
      (ml, MergeL [y]) -> foldMap f ml <> f y
      (MergeL [x], mr) -> f x <> foldMap f mr
      (ml, MergeL []) -> foldMap f ml
      (MergeL [], mr) -> foldMap f mr
      (ml, mr) -> foldMap f ml <> foldMap f mr
```

This gives acceptable performance -- same complexity and order of magnitude of timings than the plain implementation without optimisations, and about the same performance with optimisations.